# Azure Blob Storage - Point-in-time restore Does it affect other containers?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Here is my Blob Storage.

```
Blob Storage
     |-- test1 (container)
     |-- test2 (container)
     |-- test3 (container)
     |-- ...
```

If I restored like the following, will I affect other containers(test2, test3)? For example, during Azure Storage was restoring `test1`, **would Azure Storage stop other containers from downloading, updating, downloading, listing, etc?**  I want something official or evidence.

[image]

---

### The reason why I ask this question.

[Official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/point-in-time-restore-manage?tabs=portal) says that data operations on the blobs in the ranges being restored are blocked.

> When you perform a restore operation, Azure Storage blocks data operations on the blobs in the ranges being restored for the duration of the operation. Read, write, and delete operations are blocked in the primary location. For this reason, operations such as listing containers in the Azure portal may not perform as expected while the restore operation is underway.

But actually, some data operations on the blobs out of the range are blocked. For example, uploading is bocked.

```
Blob ranges: test1/New Directory/ ~ test1/New Directory1/


[2021-10-14T07:35:32.524Z] ================ Uploading =====================
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.524Z] Uploading to Azure storage as blob:
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.524Z]       quickstart2021-10-14T07:35:3.txt
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z]
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z] [ERROR] RestError: The point in time restore is in progress.
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z] RequestId:4e9ed757-e01e-009b-70ce-c077eb000000
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z] Time:2021-10-14T07:35:32.5917845Z
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z]     at handleErrorResponse (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:3132:19)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z]     at /Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:3068:49
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z]     at async StorageRetryPolicy.attemptSendRequest (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/dist/index.js:14657:24)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z]     at async TracingPolicy.sendRequest (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:4282:30)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z]     at async StorageClientContext.sendOperationRequest (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:4638:31)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z]     at async BlockBlobClient.upload (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/dist/index.js:20293:20)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z]     at async uploadDRead (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/testStore/index.js:79:32)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.579Z]     at async module.exports (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/testStore/index.js:28:10)



[2021-10-14T07:35:32.704Z] Uploading to Azure storage as blob:
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.704Z]       New Directory/aa.json
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z]
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z] [ERROR] RestError: The point in time restore is in progress.
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z] RequestId:4e9ed7ad-e01e-009b-30ce-c077eb000000
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z] Time:2021-10-14T07:35:32.7719106Z
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z]     at handleErrorResponse (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:3132:19)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z]     at /Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:3068:49
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z]     at async StorageRetryPolicy.attemptSendRequest (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/dist/index.js:14657:24)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z]     at async TracingPolicy.sendRequest (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:4282:30)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z]     at async StorageClientContext.sendOperationRequest (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:4638:31)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z]     at async BlockBlobClient.upload (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/dist/index.js:20293:20)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z]     at async upsert (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/testStore/index.js:96:32)
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.760Z]     at async module.exports (/Users/user/WebstormProjects/cosmosdb-manager/functions/testStore/index.js:37:10)
```

And I can list and read all files on the range.

```
[2021-10-14T07:35:31.854Z] ================ listing =====================
[2021-10-14T07:35:31.968Z] New Directory/20200121.md
[2021-10-14T07:35:31.972Z] New Directory/20200127.md
[2021-10-14T07:35:31.973Z] New Directory/aa.json
[2021-10-14T07:35:31.973Z] quickstart2021-10-14.txt
[2021-10-14T07:35:31.973Z] quickstart2021-10-14T02:37:3.txt
[2021-10-14T07:35:31.974Z] quickstart2021-10-14T02:38:0.txt
[2021-10-14T07:35:31.974Z] quickstart2021-10-14T02:40:1.txt
[2021-10-14T07:35:31.974Z] quickstart2021-10-14T02:42:3.txt
[2021-10-14T07:35:31.974Z] quickstart2021-10-14T02:56:4.txt

[2021-10-14T07:35:32.028Z] Downloaded blob New Directory/20200121.md content...
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.032Z]       We are going to discuss the following topics in tomorrow's meeting.
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.088Z]
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.088Z] Downloaded blob New Directory/20200127.md content...
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.094Z]       tell me where he is and I'll be on my way
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.149Z]
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.149Z] Downloaded blob New Directory/aa.json content...
[2021-10-14T07:35:32.154Z]       Hello, World! 2021-10-14T04:23:2
```

So I am so confusing.

Comment: Hello @kyakya, I believe your Storage account is of GRS replication type ? please let me know if i am correct

Comment: Based on the above , Then only Write operations will fail during the point to restore operation duration. Read will be available from the secondary location as primary will used for the point to restore operation and listing might work unexpected sometimes.